# Combine agent with tools and MultiRootChain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I would like to use a `MultiRootChain` to use one QA chain, and an "agents" with tools.
But, to use tools, I need to create an agent, via `initialize_agent(tools,llm,agent=agent_type,...)`.

For `MultiRootChain`, I need a `Chain`, and not an `Agent`.
How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 0):

Try MultiRetrievalQAChain, you can add multiple agents as retrievers. And one of the agent can be QA answering one.